# PDO fetch all problems not solved

Tags: php, mysql

I've got one table called books
in my database.  I've got users who are admin and not admins have boolean 0 assigned to them,
so I have a function but I only want admins to be able to execute the function.

Therefore I need to check the database with their username and whether they are admins that is type==0 or not.  I have to do this all in PDO statements.

```
$sqls =$handle->prepare("SELECT type FROM 888 WHERE 888='{$_COOKIE['888']}'");
$sqls->execute();
$row  = $sqls -> fetch();


if($row['type']==0){do the function}
```

yet it does not show any error or anything else. Can you see and explain the problem?

Comment: sorry 888 is just put i didnt want to give all details sorry

Comment: You need to post something that demonstrates the problem. What I see here won't work because you've replace parts of the query with syntactically invalid numbers. For all I know the original is just as bad.

Comment: is 888 supposed to be both a column name and a table name? that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/22974685/1864610

Comment: You have unescaped quotes in: `'{$_COOKIE['888']}'` escape the inner-most single quotes.

Comment: If you were good enough to have a job that required secrecy, you wouldnt be on here.

Comment: if telling us the table\colume name is an issue, you have real problems, don't make it hard to help you.

Comment: @jonny, if you solve fetching all problems tell me, surely I want to know how it works to delete them all `*` after that from my life :D
Now seriously, update your question with proper title and description/content. Other visitors should understand the matter of the question as much as possible from your topic title.

Answer (score 1):

This is bad. You are using a cookie (client-side) to check if a visitor has administrator rights. What's to stop anybody from just changing the cookie? Store the administrator flag value in a session (server-side) when the user logs in.

On login:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['admin'] = 1; // for example
```

On your specific page:

```
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['admin'] === 1)
{
  // do the function
}
```

And you save yourself from doing an unnecessary database query, solving your problem in the process.

Comment: @jonny this is good advice, because your approach is neither secure, nor optimal one (performance). Read about PHP sessions.

Comment: ok so i did that but it says admin is undefined ???

Comment: @jonny Hard to tell without seeing your code, but take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php/8028987#8028987

Answer (score 0):

Use $_SESSION instead. But ...

```
$mycookie = $_COOKIE['888'];
$sqls = $handle->prepare("SELECT type FROM `888` WHERE `888` = ? LIMIT 1");
$sqls->bindParam(1, $mycookie, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$row = false;
try {
    $sqls->execute();
    $row = $sqls->fetch();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

if ($row) {
    // may want to print_r($row) and debug...
    if($row['type']==0) {

    }
}
```

Comment: i did that but it says admin is undefined ?

Comment: its working thanks guys used cookies for it